# Entering the Training Complex in Valorant Tutorial

Tags: valorant

I got stuck in the very beginning of Valorant tutorial. I managed to jump over a pile of rubbish and crouch under another to obtain a handgun. After this I don't know how to get forward. There is a half open door but the gap is too narrow to go through and there seems to be no way to move the door. None of the keybindings seem to be related to interacting with the environment. I tried destroying the door with the handgun and knife but they seem to do only temporary damage on the door. There are also two blue force fields that seem impenetrable. By going back and standing on top of the first rubbish pile, I'm able to strafe jump on top of the other. I could perhaps climb over the wall from that position if there was some way to perform a jump and ledge grab combo but there doesn't seem to be support for such maneuvers. There are also lots of extra scrap in the air which makes me think it might be possible to get over the fence by doing some insane strafe jump tricks. However, this feels too advanced to be the intended solution for the situation.

Comment: I have had the bug where the drone does not appear and had to restart the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After obtaining the handgun, a flying drone with a target attached to its body should appear hovering to your left, which the voiceover will ask you to shoot down. Shooting this drone down will disable one of the impenetrable blue force fields and allow you to progress further into the tutorial, which will see you taking a path further around the area and shooting humanoid bots. You can see the intended progress here:

If no drone has appeared for you, you may have hit a bug and should attempt to restart the tutorial.